# Logout method requires a db name as first argument (Node.js driver for Mongo)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I get an error "logout method requires a db name as first argument" in logout method of MongoClient in the driver for Node.js.
Does anyone know what is this problem, because I think I do everything correctly:

```
mongoClient.logout({dbName: 'test'}, callback)
```

Comment: mongoClient hase mongoclient.close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was that I did not specify database to authenticate against in the `mongoClient.connect` function via `authSource` parameter in the options.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first argument (options) is optional, have you tried

```
mongoClient.logout(callback);
```

or

```
mongoClient.logout();
```

Or is it that you only want to logout from 'test'?.

You have more info here:
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html

**EDIT**

I am suspecting that the problem could be that mongoClient expects a string in the first argument. Could you try this

```
mongoClient.logout('test', () => {console.log("logging out")});
```

Comment: Well, the error occurs even when I don't use options. Actually, yes, I just want to logout from 'test'.

Comment: and what is the error message when you try .logout() ?

Comment: @Guseyn Ismayylov , I edited the answer could you give it a try?

Comment: I tried it first when I saw the problem, but I get the same error when I use first argument as string. But when I use mongoClient.logout('test', {}, () => {}) error does not occur, but it does not finish the process, I guess because callback should be second argument. Well, it's really weird..

Comment: Ok, but you need only two parameters, something like

    mongoClient.logout('test', () => {console.log("logging out")});

Comment: Perhaps It did not end because the callback was empty

Comment: Sorry, yes, it must be one or two params, and the last one is callback, I actually get an error: "final argument to `executeOperation` must be a callback". But the problem is not gone..